# Solve the partial differential equation $y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^3y+xy^3, x> 0, y> 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Problem is to solve the differential equation
$$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^3y+xy^3,  x> 0, y> 0$$

using variables $u = x^2+y^2, v = x^2-y^2$

I have started at a solution with the chain rule, I have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+ 2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} $$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$
Plug in that in the differential equation I get
$$y(2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial v})-x(2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial v})=x^3y+xy^3 \iff 4xy \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = x^3y+xy^3 $$ 
But I am stuck here.

Comment: You next need to convert the $x$ and $y$ to $u$ and $v$ in your last equation.

Comment: @Paul I was thinking that too, but I am not sure how to do this to only have an equation of u och v variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cancellation you get

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{1}{4}u$$
The right hand side is constant in $v$, and so it can be directly integrated, yielding
$$f(u,v)=\frac{1}{4}uv+g(u)$$

Comment: How did you do the cancellation (my math skills are quite rusty at the moment)

Comment: Just divide both sides by $xy$.

Comment: I get that (x^3*y+xy^3)/(4xy) = (x^2+y^2)/4. So that means that the right side of the equation becomes u/4? How did you get (1/4)x^2 ?

Comment: Oh, I missed the second part of the equation!  Let me edit.

Comment: I think maybe f(u,v) = (1/4)v + g(u) ? (without the extra u) since that is the result of integration of right side of the equation?

Comment: The $u$ acts as a constant.  So just like the antiderivative of $2$ is $2v$, the antiderivative of $u$ is $uv$.